# Having problems with init function in javascript and using the properties after assigning in init function

Tags: javascript, init

I am writing three classes and want to display something, the last class uses an init function to assign values to its properties, see below. But it doesn't work as I expected.

```
class Circle1 {
    constructor(options) {

  }

  render() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Hello, ';
  }
}

class Circle2 {
    constructor(options) {

  }

  render() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'My';
  }
}

class Circle {
    constuctor(options) {
        this.x = options.x;
        this.y = options.y;
        this.length = options.length;

        this.bodies = [];
        this.init(options);
    }

    init(options) {
        this.first = new Circle1(options);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this.bodies.push(new Circle2(options));
        }
    }

    render() {
    /**
    this.first.render();

    this.bodies.forEach(function(body) {
        body.render();
    });
    **/
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'World';

    }
}

var c = new Circle({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    length: 6
});

c.render();
```

This code will display "World" to the screen.

However, if I uncomment the commented code, and try to display "Hello, My (times length) World" to the screen but it doesn't show anything.

I am very confused with the init function in the class. I thought I can assign values to the properties in that function but the result tells me it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CHvFk/153/) link.

Comment: Why do you use an `init` function at all? Just put that code in the constructor.

Comment: There's a difference between `.innerHTML = ` and `.innerHTML +=`

Comment: @Bergi, I just want to get the hang of `init` function. I don't know how it works. I have read some code and want to test using it myself. What is the difference? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: There is not much of a difference (technicalities, mostly), that's why it's so useless and unnecessary to have an `init` method additionally to the constructor.

Comment: @newguy `constructor` is invoked upon the instantiation of the Class, while `init` isn't and has to be run from inside the `constructor`

Comment: You have a typo in declaration class Circle: `constuctor` vs `constRuctor`?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja so I was doing it correctly? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @stdob-- you can check out jsfiddle link above. Same thing. And it displays "World"

Comment: @newguy It just seems like bad code organization to split up your constructor for no discernible reason, but, no, the code is still correct in that aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the name of the `constructor` (constructor is not called):

```
class Circle {
    constuctor(options) {
```

==>

```
class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/5sv5hwLb/ ]

Comment: OK thanks for pointing that out. I thought there isn't a problem because it still displayed "World", why would that happen?

Comment: Yes I know that's after the correction. Before I made the change in your answer the screen displayed "World". Why doesn't javascript show an error saying the constructor doesn't pass and not able to create an object of `Circle`?

Comment: @newguy Because the `constructor` is not necessarily to declare.